# What tools are available to generate key-pair, enroll with SCEP, use for TLS server on .Net?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, cryptography, ocsp

The specification I am working with requires that a key-pair be generated and a certificate be automatically enrolled via SCEP to a specified server and used as both a TLS server and client certificate with OCSP validation of the counterparty.  Are there any tools available for .Net to do this sort of thing?

Pure-managed code and Compact Framework support would be a Good Thing, as I am attempting to produce a unified MSIL binary that runs unmodified on CF/ARMv4i, .Net/x86 and .Net/x64, though something that only works for .Net/x86 is useful in the short term.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SecureBlackbox by EldoS implements such functionality, but it is commercial product.
Also there are some free components (BouncyCastle, for instance).
However, no one of them implements SCEP, so you'll need to do it.

Comment: Fair enough.  I actually ended up using BouncyCastle for both OCSP and the underpinnings of my own SCEP implementation.  I haven't gotten around to TLS yet, although the Mentalis library looks like a promising starting point -- IIRC Padarn uses a port of Mentalis to CF.